# Silene virginica Endangered in FL

Tags: botany, ecology, conservation-biology

Why is *Silene virginica*, colloquially known as Fire Pink, endangered in Florida? What factors besides human industrialization are affecting its survival there?

Answer (score 1):

Various factors from different sources:

-- Diseases like Anther Smut Disease ([reference](http://people.virginia.edu/~ja8n/Publications/1996%20Antonovics,%20Stratton,%20Thrall,%20Jarosz%201996.pdf)).

-- Rampant use of herbicides.

-- Invasion of exotic pest species ([reference](http://www.georgiawildlife.org/sites/default/files/uploads/wildlife/nongame/pdf/accounts/plants/silene_regia.pdf)).

-- Spatiotemporal variation in the pollination of Silene virginica by the ruby-throat hummingbird which is its principal pollinator ([reference](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2680202?uid=3737496&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21104280742563)).